# Creating Dynamic Advice by Passing in Strategies to Aspect

Tags: java, annotations, aop, aspectj

I am trying to make my *advice* more *dynamic* based on the class/method it is providing *advice* for. Looking for something like this pseudoish code:

```
class Activity
   private TheAdviceStrategyInterface activityAdviceStrategy = new ActivityAdviceStrategy();

@Entity(adviceStrategy = activityAdviceStrategy)
public void doSomething(ActivityInput ai) { ... }
```

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Entity {
    public TheAdviceStrategyInterface adviceStrategy();
}
```

```
@Aspect
public class TheAdvice {
    @Around("@annotation(entity)")
    public Object doStuff (ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Entity entity) { 
        ...
        TheAdviceStrategyInterface theStrat = entity.adviceStrategy();
        ....
    }

}
```

But of course we can not have Objects or Interfaces as annotation parameters.

Any "advice" on how I can implement this? I basically want one Aspect annotation to handle very similar situations, with a slight difference depending on which class is using the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

> But of course we can not have Objects or Interfaces as Annotation
> parameters. Any "advice" on how I can implement this?

1- Create a String parameter in the `Entity` interface to represent the possible strategies:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    public @interface Entity {
        public String adviceStrategy();
    }
```

2- Create a class that implements the [factory pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm), for instance:

```
public class TheAdviceStrategyFactory {
    
   //use getShape method to get object of type shape 
   public TheAdviceStrategyInterface getStrategy(String strategy){
      if(strategy == null){
         return null;
      }     
      if(strategy.equalsIgnoreCase("Strategy1")){
         return new TheAdviceStrategy1();
         
      } else if(strategy.equalsIgnoreCase("Strategy2")){
         return new TheAdviceStrategy2();
      
      return null;
   }
}
```

with the Classes `TheAdviceStrategy1` and `TheAdviceStrategy2` implementing the interface `TheAdviceStrategyInterface`.

Take advantage of both in the *advice*:

```
@Aspect
public class TheAdvice {
    @Around("@annotation(entity)")
    public Object doStuff (ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Entity entity) { 
        ...
        TheAdviceStrategyFactory factory = new TheAdviceStrategyFactory(); 
        TheAdviceStrategyInterface theStrat = factory.getStrategy(entity.adviceStrategy());
        ....
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks I will probably go with this. I was thinking of using factory as well. Either that or override a method in the Advice class.

Comment: @john [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)